# How to set cookie in JMeter that is usually set via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jmeter

I am testing a web application.
In the navigation menu of the main page, when a node is clicked, a javascript function will be called. I look up this function, the page will set `document.cookie="current_moduleId=xxxx;path=/"` before redirect to the target page.

So how can I set cookie in JMeter for every request?

Comment: See http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/writnng-to-reading-to-cookies-td522380.html. I wasn't able to get it to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the following pan:

[image]

In BeanShell pre processor, put :

```
  import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
  import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
  CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("toto","titi","localhost","/",false,0);
  manager.add(cookie);
```

Note that using JSR223 PreProcessor + Groovy + Caching will be better for performances

Comment: I can't eval the variable sampler.

Comment: Replace `sampler` with `ctx.getCurrentSampler()`

Answer (score 0):

For people who come across this in future, I had to use 0 or -1 for the expiry time of the cookie:

`Cookie cookie = new Cookie("toto","titi","localhost","/",false,-1);`

Any positive integers seemed to not set the cookie