# how to create and call a custom function in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am using JMeter for load testing, I am creating 1000 threads each sending an http request as follows:

```
{"email" : "test${__threadNum}@test.com"}
```

that's working fine, now I need to add a more complicated scenario. I need to pass email encrypted with my custom encryption method.

```
something like:  {"email" : MyCustomClass.encypt("test${__threadNum}@test.com")}
```

Is there a way to call custom java classes from JMeter.

Comment: any feedback on this ? if answer is ok you should accept it so that it helps others

Comment: actually I want to include my jar, and then call a method from that jar, so far I am not successful.

Comment: where did you put your jar ? are you sure it is fine ? if yes look into jmeter.log and show error

Comment: i put it in the lib/ext folder

Comment: you must put it in lib not lib/ext

Comment: any feedback ? is your issue fixed, if yes you should accept answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found is to edit the file BeanShellFunction.bshrc and add java methods there,

```
String encryptSession(String email) {
    // TODO encrypt session!
    return new String(email);
}
```

and then add this to the http request body:

```
${__BeanShell(encryptSession("test${__threadNum}@test.com"))}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSR 223 sampler or preprocessor and use Groovy as underlying language.
To do so add groovy-all.jar in jmeter/lib folder.

If you want to use your already existing jar, put it in jmeter/lib also.

Comment: what is the syntax to call java methods in jmeter. I expect something like this in the request body {"email" : MyCustomClass.encypt("test${__threadNum}@test.com")} but not sure about the syntax

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680350/how-to-set-cookie-in-jmeter-that-is-usually-set-via-javascript for an example

Comment: The sampler (groovy or beanshell) puts the var using vars.put (''test'', the var) then use it with ${thevar}